# Displacement is not working!

Tags: texturing, uv, displacement

Why my displavement is not working?
Even if you adjust the height or level, only the size of the object decreases.
[image]

[image]

https://pasteall.org/blend/00821a11fb1a4a27bd83dfc818a3ab6b

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132165/discussion-on-question-by-taehyun-lee-displacement-is-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Your both files works for me (if I plug any black&white image into "Height" socket of Displacement node).

Just to be sure ... effect can be seen only in Render view mode only.

So ... your file seems to be set right ... If your issue persist try to render only by CPU (in case it is GPU issue).

[image]